# I can't Upload Profile Picture for a new user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to create a new User, where I have to input the name, email, etc and i also wanted to upload the images directly from the web and then display it in my index page, but when i tried to insert a new user and upload the profile picture it just returns null

This input for the profile picture

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="User.Photo" class="control-label"></label>
    <input type="file" asp-for="User.Photo" class="custom-file-input form-control" />
</div>
```

This is my OnPost Method for adding the data to my database

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    
    var currentUser = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Username");

    if (currentUser != null)
    {
        var findUser = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == currentUser);
        if(findUser == null)
        {
            
            return Page();
        }
        int RoleID = findUser.RoleID;
        // if the customer is sales return to page
        if(RoleID == 1)  
        {
            IsAdmin = false;
            return Page();
        }
    }

    if (Photo != null)
    {
        if (User.ProfilePicturePath != null)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "ProfilePicture", User.ProfilePicturePath);
        }
        User.ProfilePicturePath = ProcessUploadedFile();
    }


    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.User.Add(User);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");

}
```

this is the ProssesUploadedFile method

```
private string ProcessUploadedFile()
{
    string uniqueFileName = null;
    if(Photo != null)
    {
        string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "ProfilePicture");
        uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Photo.FileName;
        string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);  
        using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Photo.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
    return uniqueFileName;
}
```

I want to insert the picture when i run it and save the picture according to the user that i just created and i aslo wanted to view the user list in my index page, where the list of user is in a card class

Comment: While uploading new picture, have you checked, if the image has been saved to your folder and the related path has been saved to the database?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to insert the picture when i run it and save the picture
> according to the user that i just created and i aslo wanted to view
> the user list in my index page, where the list of user is in a card
> class

Well, based on your scenario and description, It seems that the way you are trying to upload picture and link to your view is incorrect. You are missing the `name="photo"` property which is your property name.

First of all you have to upload the image as `IFormFile` along with your existing class, let's say, employee or user class. You should better use ViewModel.

While you would upload the picture, it should get the image as `IFormFile` and need to copy the stream and save it to your wwwroot folder.

After that, you should map the path of that image with your profile image. Finally when you would display the image, just bring the image path based on your userId and display in your veiw using `<img src="~/Photos/@item.ImageName"`

Let's have a look, you we could implement that:

Demo Model:

Let's say, you have following model:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public Employee? Employee { get; set; }
    public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; }
}


public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    public string? ImageName { get; set; }
    public string? ImageLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateEmployee(Employee model, IFormFile photo)
{

    if (photo == null || photo.Length == 0)
    {
        return Content("File not selected");
    }
    var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Photos", photo.FileName);


    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
        stream.Close();
    }

    model!.ImageName = photo.FileName;

    if (model == null)
    {
        return Content("Invalid Submission!");
    }
    var emp = new Employee
    {
        Name = model.Name,
        Gender = model.Gender,
        DOB = model.DOB,
        ImageName = model.ImageName,
        ImageLocation = path,
    };

    _context.Add(emp);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Wwwroot:

Make sure you have `Photos folder` within your wwwroot folder as following:

[image]

View To Uplaod:

```
@model Employee

    <form asp-action="CreateEmployee" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Gender" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="DOB" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="DOB" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DOB" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="chooseFile"><input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

When Display:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var employees = _context.Employees.ToList();
    return View(employees);
   
}
```

View to display:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProofOfConceptProject.Models.Employee>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}


<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DOB)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageName)
            </th>
            <th>
                Member Details
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-controller="Application" asp-action="DownloadImage" asp-route-imageName="@item.ImageName" />
                    <img src="~/Photos/@item.ImageName"
                         class="rounded-square"
                         height="50" width="75"
                         style="border:1px"
                         asp-append-version="true" accept="image/*" />
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="DeleteConfirmed" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-Id="@item.EmployeeId">Delete</a> |  <a asp-action="EditMember" class="btn btn-warning" asp-route-memberId="@item.EmployeeId">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Database:

You should design your database as following:

[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0) for more example.